Lighting on edges are just stopping / not mixing
I have a weird issue with the Unity game engine. In the game there are rooms which have lights. The rooms are procedurally generated, and said rooms have lights in them. However, the lights in each room are not mixing with each other. (I am using pro builder for the level design.)
I believe I am using standard shaders.

Another small issue I have is that lights straight up stop working if looked at from the wrong angle or too far away.
I have tried changing the Quality in Project Settings, the Lighting window, and changing the lights themselves, but nothing seems to be working.

Are your lights static / baked?

I had solved this with setting all of my lights Render Modes to "Important"
